# WinUI3 ListView Getting the position where the item is dropped

Tags: windows, winui-3

Having  ListView, how can I get the index in the list where the item from the same list was dropped?(Reordering) I tried using the following callbacks, but neither `DragItemsCompletedEventArgs` or `OnDropIntoStagedPhotos` seem to have an appropriate method.

```
void TableContentPage::OnStagedDragItemsCompleted(
    [[maybe_unused]] ::winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const &,
    [[maybe_unused]] ::winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls::
        DragItemsCompletedEventArgs const &args)
{

}

void TableContentPage::OnDropIntoStagedPhotos(
    [[maybe_unused]] Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const  &sender,
    [[maybe_unused]] Microsoft::UI::Xaml::DragEventArgs const &args)
{
}
```

I'm using the following ListView attributes:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListViewName"
          Grid.Row="0"
          Grid.Column="0"
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
          ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled="True"
          CanDragItems="True"
          CanReorderItems="True"
          IsSwipeEnabled="True"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          AllowDrop="True"
          Background="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}"
          Drop="OnDropIntoStagedPhotos"
          DragOver="OnDragOverStagedPhotos"
          DragItemsCompleted="OnStagedDragItemsCompleted"
          DragItemsStarting="OnStagedDragItemsStarting"
          SelectionMode="Extended"
          SelectionChanged="OnStagedPhotosSelectionChanged">
```

Answer (score 0):

[ListViewBase.DragItemsCompleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.dragitemscompleted?view=windows-app-sdk-1.4#event-type) gives the dragged items and with [IVector.IndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.collections.ivector-1.indexof?view=winrt-22621), you can retrieve the index. So, we only need to distinguish between reorder and move. It's necessary for the destination to give the difference.

There is a UWP [XamlDragAndDrop](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/XamlDragAndDrop) sample you can refer to.

```
/// <summary>
/// Drop on the Trash
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
void Scenario1_ListView::TargetTextBlock_Drop(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::DragEventArgs^ e)
{
    if (e->DataView->Contains(StandardDataFormats::Text))
    {
        // We need to take the deferral as the source will read _deletedItem which
        // we cannot set synchronously
        auto def = e->GetDeferral();
        create_task(e->DataView->GetTextAsync()).then([this, e, def](String^ s)
        {
            _deletedItem = s;
            e->AcceptedOperation = DataPackageOperation::Move;
            def->Complete();
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: `TargetTextBlock_Drop` is a callback for the `Drop` event. Drop is not triggered when reordering, only when droping an item from a different component.

Comment: `TargetTextBlock_Drop`, which indicates the `_deletedItem` to be deleted for `TargetListView`, is the event of `TargetTextBlock`. Seen [the case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1403863/winui3-getting-the-index-where-the-item-was-moved), you like the solution listening for events in the ObservableCollection.